# Automapper и коллекции

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, automapper

Допустим, у меня есть 2 объекта, которые внутри себя имеют еще и поля в виде коллекций.

С полями все понятно и нужно тупо вызывать:

```
  ForMember(dst => dst.Comment, src => src.MapFrom(c => c.Comment))
```

А как быть с коллекциями, если имена полей в них не совпадают между источником и приемником?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Определить маппин для типов которые испольются в колекциях отдельно, тогда `Automapper` сможет использовать этот маппинг автоматически, например ([Nested Mapping](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Nested-mappings.html), [List and Arrays](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Lists-and-arrays.html)):

```
class User
{
    public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}

class Comment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class UserDto
{
    public List<CommentDto> Data { get; set; }
}

class CommentDto
{
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}

var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    // сначала мапим типы и коллекций
    cfg.CreateMap<CommentDto, Comment>()
        .ForMember(dst => dst.Id, src => src.MapFrom(c => c.Prop1))
        .ForMember(dst => dst.Name, src => src.MapFrom(c => c.Prop2));

    // тут автомапер уже автоматически будет использовать существующий маппинг
    cfg.CreateMap<UserDto, User>()
        .ForMember(dst => dst.Comments, src => src.MapFrom(c => c.Data));
});
```